# Elasticsearch geo_distance filter - distance unit set to km but seems to calculate with meters

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using geo_distance filter to get the points that are within a certain distance to a reference point. As a distance_unit I set km, however, when I'm running my code I'm pretty sure that Elastic calculates meters, and not kilometers (so in this particular case below I get the points that are within 20 meters, not 20 kilometers).

Any ideas why is it using meters rather than kilometers?

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "_id": {
                                    "value": idnum
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": 20,
                    "distance_unit": "km",
                    "geopoint": {
                        "lat": lat,
                        "lon": lng
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html#_options_3)? There doesn't seem to be a `distance_unit` option. Include it in `"distance": "20km"`

Comment: I did but thanks for your suggestion. When you create your query in sense the above code is the one that comes up as default for the geo_distance filter. I'm guessing that Marvel/sense is more up to date than the docs but I might be wrong.

Comment: Can't find any `distance_unit` in elasticsearch source code. Maybe your Marvel installation requires some dev-branch version of ES? Or it is a bug in Marvel. I'm using ES distance filter successfully with specifying the unit within the `distance` setting (ES 1.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `"distance": "20KM", rather than distance_unit....`